# Reactivity with Vue Array of Objects

Tags: vue.js, reactive

Hope you are safe and healthy!

I am working on a vue custom compoment where I am using v-for to render the child cards for each assets (Child Component). Each child card has a check-box which is pertaining to the selection of the card by end-user.

Now, parent has a select-All and unselect-All feature to check/uncheck all the child cards.

I may be following a wrong approach. But selectAll and unselect All not updating the state of selected property.

#### Parent Comp:

**Template**

```html
<div class="cotent-wrapper">
  <div v-for="(item, index) in assetsList" :key="index">
    <asset-item :data="item" update-selction="updateSelectedAsset($event) ">
    </asset-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
data() {
   return {
      selectedAssets: []
   }
},
computed: {
   ...mapGetters({
      assetsList: 'AssetList'
   })
},
methods: {
        ...mapActions({
            fetchAssets: 'getContentDeliveryAssets'
        }),
        markAll: function(selected) {
            if (selected) {
                this.assetsList.forEach(item => item['selected'] = true)
            } else
                this.assetsList.forEach(item => item['selected'] = false)
        }
    }
```

#### Child Component

**Template**

```html
<div class="asset-card">
    <b-form-checkbox size="lg" v-model="sel" :id="data.asset_id" @change="updateSelection()"></b-form-checkbox>
    <div class="img-wrap "><img :src="data.asset_url" /></div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```js
data() {
        return {
            data: {},
            sel: false
        }
    },
    watch: {
        // eslint-disable-next-line
        data: {
            handle: function(newVal) { // watch it
                console.log(newVal)
                    // this.sel = newVal
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

Comment: If `assetsList` is in your store, you should definitely not be making direct changes. Instead, you should be committing a mutation

Comment: Yes assetList is in store and I am not making any call to action to mutate the value. Will that resolve issue?

Answer (score 0):

Since `assetsList` is coming from your Vuex store's `AssetList` getter, you should not be making direct changes. If you set Vuex to [strict mode](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/strict.html), this would actually start throwing errors.

Instead, you should create a mutation for `markAll` and commit it from your component.

For example

```js
// store
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true, // always a good idea
  state: {
    AssetList: [] // just guessing here
  },
  getters: {
    AssetList: state => state.AssetList // also guessing
  },
  mutations: {
    markAll: (state, selected) => {
      // it's best to treat state as immutable and assign new values
      // rather than try to change them
      state.AssetList = state.AssetList.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        selected
      }))
    }
  }
})
```

and in your component

```js
methods: {
  ...mapMutations(['markAll']),
  ...mapActions({
    fetchAssets: 'getContentDeliveryAssets'
  }
}
```

---

For handling changes to individual items, you'll obviously need another mutation

```js
mutations: {
  markItem: (state, { item, selected }) => {
    const storeItem = state.AssetList.find(storeItem => storeItem === item)
    if (storeItem) storeItem.selected = selected
  },
  // markAll...
}
```

and in your child component, use a computed property with *getter* and *setter* to handle change events

```html
<b-form-checkbox
  size="lg"
  v-model="sel"
  :id="data.asset_id"></b-form-checkbox>
```

```js
import { mapMutations } from 'vuex'
export default {
  props: { data: Object },
  computed: {
    sel: {
      get () { return this.data.selected },
      set (selected) { this.markItem({ item: this.data, selected }) }
    }
  },
  methods: mapMutations(['markItem'])
}
```

Comment: Makes sense! However, with this approach I had been recieving the below:


``` js
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at Watcher.run (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4568)
    at flushSchedulerQueue (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:4310)
    at Array.eval (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1980)
    at flushCallbacks (vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1906)
```